"Wrong Volume" ? Need testnet3 tBTC?
Why do I keep getting "Wrong Volume" from all the testnet faucets?
What does that mean & how can I fix it?

I'm a developer trying to write an educational & safe testnet/signet/regtest wallet.
I need tBTC for testing & transacting between myself & others.
If there are any kind souls w/ any testnet3 tBTC to spare, here is my address:
     tb1qv5s0m4q2vkj9tl3zfj60szzw0qdstjuu6eznj7

1 to 5 tBTC would be helpful (or, indeed, any amount).
Thanks in advance...?

Which testnet faucets have you tried, and which is the one in the screenshot?

screenshot: https://bitcoinfaucet.uo1.net/send.php

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet#Faucets

You said that you were trying to use the faucet on bitcoinfaucet.uo1.net. The site shows its limit for payouts near the top:

I would expect that if you set an amount larger than that, it will might return the "Wrong volume" error. Unfortunately, some people have started monetizing testnet coins and are trying to monopolize coins by sucking up everything from easily accessible sources. The only solution that comes to mind is to frequently restart testnet in order for them to lose money, but that also makes it less useful to other users.
You could try the other faucets listed in this community wiki, or try to find an individual that can send you some.

I'll check out those other sites thanks.
I do not exceed allowable amounts from the sites.

just reviewed that list.  The only ones that "work" are those I've tried already.  The others are listed as defunct sadly.
